# How can pressure altitude be calculated manually using hPa?

Tags: ppl

I am currently going through PPL and sitting for the meteorological paper and I see this question in the mock exam.

> What is the approximate International Standard Atmosphere (ISA)
> standard pressure at FL 180?

The answer has it as 500 mba but I can't seem to get the answer anywhere. What's the best formula I should use in this sort of questions?

Comment: I remember studying from an EASA book that used the rule of thumb where 1 mb=30’ change. That way, FL180 would have 413 mb. If the answer is 500mb, they took 1mb=35’. I used the an iPhone app based CX3, and it seems to be take 30’ as well. Strange!

Comment: @PapaMike99 the pressure gradient changes over altitude. At sea level, the gradient is approximatly 27 ft / mb, at FL180 it is approximately 48 ft / mb.

Comment: @DeltaLima I had totally forgotten about that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For altitudes in the troposphere, use this, which I give here in Excel format:

`= 1013.25 * ( 1 - ( 0.0000068755856 * 18000 ) ) ^5.2558797`

This yields a result of 505.99 mB at 18,000 feet.

The generalized form of this is:

`= isoSLpressure * ( 1 - ( 0.0000068755856 * altFt ) ) ^5.2558797`

Where:

- isoSLpressure is your choice of *any* ISO sea level pressure (29.92", 1013.25mB, 760.0mm, or 14.696psi, they all work the same.)
- altFt is altitude MSL in feet.

This formula basically calculates the pressure RATIO of the atmosphere at any given altitude, which is a different way of applying the pressure lapse rate.

All credit goes to [Ed Williams](https://edwilliams.org/avform147.htm).

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, was missing the second closing parenthesis in the formulas.  Fixed.

Comment: Hi Max, which Ed Williams are you referring to? Wikipedia gives me an [actor and several football players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Williams). I also found a [pilot boat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_F._Williams_(pilot_boat)) but that is as close to aviation as I got.

Comment: @DeltaLima Ed has been the long time de facto keeper of the Aviation Formulary, which has been a goldmine for many years.  https://edwilliams.org/avform147.htm  Not unlike other references (like the CRC math tables) the formulary is not a tutorial and is of no use in learning the concepts.  But if you already understand the concepts and just need to find a formula or constant now and then, it's a treasure chest that you'll keep a link to the rest of your life.